# Не добавляется граница для 2 таблицы с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, css

Хочу выделить таблицу границей, при нажатии кнопки. Для первой кнопки всё получилось, но когда нажимаю на 2 кнопку, граница у 2 таблицы не появляется.
В чём у меня ошибка?
Помогите пожалуйста

```js
function addition() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b').value);
  let tab = document.querySelector(".tabl");

  if (isNaN(a) == true) a = 0;
  if (isNaN(b) == true) b = 0;

  if (a > 23 || b > 59) {
    document.getElementById(7).innerHTML = "Неверно введено время";
    document.getElementById(1).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(2).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(3).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(4).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(5).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(6).innerHTML = "";
    tab.style.border = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(7).innerHTML = "Вам стоит встать в это время:";
    tab.style.border = "1px solid grey";
    for (let u = 0; u < 6; u++) {
      b = b + 30;
      a = a + 1;
      if (b > 59) {
        b = b - 60;
        a = a + 1;
      }
      if (a > 23) {
        a = a - 24;
      }
      if (b < 10 && a < 10) /* Делаем красивый вывод минут и часоvni (что бы выводило 06:09 а не 6:9)*/ {
        document.getElementById(1 + u).innerHTML = "0" + a + ":0" + b + "<br/>";
      } else
      if (b < 10) {
        document.getElementById(1 + u).innerHTML = a + ":0" + b + "<br/>";
      } else
      if (a < 10) {
        document.getElementById(1 + u).innerHTML = "0" + a + ":" + b + "<br/>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(1 + u).innerHTML = a + ":" + b + "<br/>";
      }
    }
  }
}

function addition1() // Во сколько ложиться спать
{
  var chasi = parseInt(document.getElementById('chasi').value);
  var minuta = parseInt(document.getElementById('minuta').value);
  let tab2 = document.querySelector(".tabl2");
  if (isNaN(chasi) == true) chasi = 0;
  if (isNaN(minuta) == true) minuta = 0;

  if (chasi > 23 || minuta > 59) {
    document.getElementById(17).innerHTML = "Неверно введено время";
    document.getElementById(11).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(12).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(13).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(14).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(15).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById(16).innerHTML = "";
    tab2.style.border = "";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(17).innerHTML = "Вам стоит лечь в это время:";
    tab2.style.border = "1px solid grey;";
    for (let u = 0; u < 6; u++) {
      minuta = minuta - 30;
      chasi = chasi - 1;
      if (minuta < 0) {
        minuta = minuta + 60;
        chasi = chasi - 1;
      }
      if (chasi < 0) {
        chasi = chasi + 24;
      }
      if (minuta < 10 && chasi < 10) // Делаем красивый вывод минут и часо (что бы выводило 06:09 а не 6:9)
      {
        document.getElementById(11 + u).innerHTML = "0" + chasi + ":0" + minuta + "<br/>";
      } else
      if (minuta < 10) {
        document.getElementById(11 + u).innerHTML = chasi + ":0" + minuta + "<br/>";
      } else
      if (chasi < 10) {
        document.getElementById(11 + u).innerHTML = "0" + chasi + ":" + minuta + "<br/>";
      } else {
        document.getElementById(11 + u).innerHTML = chasi + ":" + minuta + "<br/>";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url("fon.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* Фиксируем фон веб-страницы */
  background-size: cover;
  /*Запрещаем появляться куче тиаких же изображений */
}

.privet {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 1px 1px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
}

.privet::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 50.47%;
  margin-left: -18%;
  width: 35%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffd63a
}

.tabl {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 33px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tabl2 {
  max-width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 33px;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0px;
}

.WOD {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.WOD1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.Hours,
.Minutes,
.Button {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

input {
  background-color: #b73516;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #ffd63a 2px;
  outline: none;
}


/* input[type=text] {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
*/

input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=buttom]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #ffd63a;
}

input[type=button] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.poka {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 27px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive;
  text-shadow: black 1px 1px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="privet">...Выберите время, в которое вы хотите лечь спать...</div>
<div class="WOD">
  <div class="Hours"><input id="a" name="a" type="text" size="3" value="" placeholder="Часы"></div>
  <div class="Minutes"><input id="b" name="b" type="text" size="3" value="" placeholder="Минуты"></div>
  <div class="Button"><input type="button" size="3" value="Расcчитать" onclick="addition();"></div>
</div>

<div class="poka" id=7>Вам стоит проснуться в это время:</div>
<div class="tabl">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id=1></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id=2></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id=3></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id=4></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id=5></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id=6></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="privet">...Выберите время, в которое вы хотите проснуться...</div>
<div class="WOD1">
  <div class="Hours"><input id="chasi" name="a" type="text" size="3" value="" placeholder="Часы"></div>
  <div class="Minutes"><input id="minuta" name="b" type="text" size="3" value="" placeholder="Минуты"></div>
  <div class="Button"><input type="button" size="3" value="Расcчитать" onclick="addition1();"></div>
</div>

<div class="poka" id=17>Вам стоит лечь в это время:</div>
<div class="tabl2">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id=11></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id=12></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id=13></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id=14></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id=15></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div id=16></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: tab2.style.border = "1px solid grey;";  После grey точку с запятой уберите

Comment: @BearVorkuta спасибо огромное. А существуют ли плагины для VSC, которые убирают такие глупые ошибки?

Comment: не подскажу, не пользуюсь